# krajee add image using screen capture

Tags: javascript, html, file, input, bootstrap-4

Im using krajee file input to upload images to a server. I also want the ability to add files using screen capture. The idea is that when I capture an image it will appear in the fileupload preview zone.

My html

```
<input th:field="*{documents}" class="file" id="input-res-capture" type="file" multiple>

<div class="col-md-4">
    <video id="videostream" autoplay></video>
    <p><button class="btn btn-primary capture-button">Start video</button>
    <p><button class="btn btn-primary" id="screenshot-button" disabled>Take screenshot</button></p>
    <p><button class="btn btn-primary" id="stop-button">Stop</button></p>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-4">
    <img id="screenshot-img">
 </div>
```

My Krajee file upload plugin code

```
 $("#input-res-capture").fileinput({
    browseOnZoneClick: false,
    showUpload: false,
    showCancel: false,
    maxFileCount: 5,
    allowedFileExtensions: ['pdf', 'png', 'jpeg', 'jpg'],
    showPreview: true,
    removeLabel: 'Remove All',
    mainClass: "input-group-lg",
    theme: "fa",
    showBrowse: false,
    dropZoneTitle: 'Captured images will appear here',
    initialPreviewAsData: false,
    fileActionSettings: {
        showRemove: true,
        showUpload: false,
        showZoom: true,
        showDrag: false,
        showCancel: false,
    },
});
```

My screen capture code

```
const constraints = {
   video: true
};
const captureVideoButton = document.querySelector('#screenshot .capture-button');
const screenshotButton = document.querySelector('#screenshot-button');
const stopButton = document.querySelector('#stop-button');
const fileInput = document.querySelector('#input-res-capture');
const img = document.querySelector('#screenshot img');
const video = document.querySelector('#screenshot video');

const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

captureVideoButton.onclick = function(event) {
   event.preventDefault()
   navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).
      then(handleSuccess).catch(handleError);
};

screenshotButton.onclick = video.onclick = function(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  canvas.width = 200;
  canvas.height = 300;

  canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0);
  img.src = canvas.toDataURL('image/webp');
}
```

Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can add image by setting it as a preview. After you make a capture recreate the fileinput defining its src in 'initialPreview' parameter.

```
$("#input-res-capture").fileinput('destroy').fileinput({
    browseOnZoneClick: false,
    showUpload: false,
    showCancel: false,
    maxFileCount: 5,
    allowedFileExtensions: ['pdf', 'png', 'jpeg', 'jpg'],
    showPreview: true,
    removeLabel: 'Remove All',
    mainClass: "input-group-lg",
    theme: "fa",
    showBrowse: false,
    dropZoneTitle: 'Captured images will appear here',
    initialPreview: image_uri,
    initialPreviewAsData: true,
    initialPreviewFileType: 'image',
    fileActionSettings: {
        showRemove: true,
        showUpload: false,
        showZoom: true,
        showDrag: false,
        showCancel: false,
    },
});
```

Also there is an option to update the params of fileinput using

```
$("#input-res-capture").fileinput('refresh',{
                    initialPreview: image_uri,
                    initialPreviewAsData: true,
                    initialPreviewFileType: 'image',
}
```

But in my case the option with 'refresh' didn't work.